# Counting Number of Rows

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have the following code that used to echo the number of columns that was an accident and I wanted it to count rows now that I've changed it its not echoing anything. Any ideas? By the way I have already connected to the database even though it is not shown.

```
<p>
<?php
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM User_info");
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
echo $num_rows[0];

mysqli_close($con);
?>
 records in our database start your search <a href="#">here</a> today. 
</p>
```

Comment: Use like just `echo $num_rows;` without `[0]`

Comment: I'll agree with Bora.. remove the [0] to make it work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a general rule, you should minimize the traffic between your DB server and your application server.

For your specific case, that means the recommended way of "counting" is:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) FROM User_info");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$num = $row[0];
?>
```

With that request (`SELECT COUNT(*) ...`), the DB server will count rows for you. And just return that total -- possibly using *indexes* or internal data structure to return directly the result. With `SELECT *`, the server has to *retrieve* and then *send* all the data in your table. Quite expensive and rather inefficient since you don't use all these data after that in your application...

---

EDIT -- if you want a "simple" explanation: what is the most efficient to know the number of pages in a book? To count them one by one, or to look at the page numbers in the footer?

With your initial solution (counting in PHP), it is like making a xerox of the book, and then counting the pages in the copy. With `COUNT(*)` you let the DB server use the page numbers or even an index (the "TOC" of the book) to find the result.

Answer (score 4):

### Here is the only right way to count rows:

```
<?php
$result = mysqli_query("SELECT count(*) FROM User_info");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$num = $row[0];
?>
<p>
<?=$num?> records in our database start your search <a href="#">here</a> today. 
</p>
```

Comment: I agree, but maybe you could explain why this is better.

Comment: Why not `mysqli_num_rows`?

Comment: @Bora when you want to know the sum on your bank account, do you request all the money in cash, count them by hand and then return to bank? Or may be you ask a bank to count them for you? Which one easier to perform?

Comment: Still not a reason why it should be the ONLY way to achieve the result.

Comment: Depends on what you want to do with the result afterwards... If you want to handle the result based on the number of rows, a count() requires two db-calls, while the mysqli_num_rows needs only one.

Comment: So if using mysqli_num_rows is wrong, why does the function exist in the first place? In what situation is using it right?

Comment: @Borniet but you don't want to handle the result based on the number. There is no use for it.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Good answer ;). @Juhana You right, not only way, thats best way. I agreed with best solution is `select count(*)`

Comment: @cuewizchris in PHP this function is almost useless. Though there are some extremely rare cases where you cannot get all the results yet you need the number. Nevertheless, this function shouldn't be used if you need only count.

Comment: @Your common sense I see your point, but then please modify your answer and explain why IN THIS CASE it's better. I would still disagree your claim that it's "the only way". That's technically not true.

Comment: The question was about how to get the count of rows.  If that's the goal, then using `count(*)` is preferred for performance reason.  YCS's bank analogy is correct.  If, on the other hand, you're going to actually use the data (along with the count), then by all means, fetch the data and use `mysqli_num_rows`.  The "the only *right* way" comment is referring to the actual question asked, which was about just counting the rows, with an implied discarding the data, after.

Answer (score 1):

mysqli_num_rows() returns its result as an integer (or string if the value is too large for an integer), not as an array, so you need to change your code from:

```
echo $num_rows[0];
```

to

```
echo $num_rows;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that one line to

```
echo $num_rows;
```